# Chrome extension to navigate to a set of links and back

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a Chrome extension to achieve the below:

1. When the extension is opened when visiting a web page (starting url), the extension extracts a url (new url) from the web page.
2. Then when a button on popup.html is clicked by the user, the extension navigates the current tab to the new url.
3. The extension waits for the new url (javascript-heavy) to be fully rendered in the current tab, and then clicks a button programmatically on the new url page to download a file.
4. Once the download completes, the extension navigates the current tab back to the starting url.

All the operations above are executed by the extension programmatically. Could you please share your thoughts how to best implement this?

I am thinking about using a background script that manages going back and forth between the starting url and the new url. This is done through the background script injecting scripts to the starting url and the new url at the right time. But since I am really new, I am not whether my thinking would work or whether there are better solutions. Your thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your idea is correct.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thank you for your feedback!